# sql: sum value row-wise conditionally

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like the following

| label1 | label2 | label3 | users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 44 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 55 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 33 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 11 |

What I am trying to do is to sum the values row wise and for example if the sum of labels become 2, then I sum the counts together (44+33).
below is the table that I am trying to build:

| label_sum | users_sum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 66 |
| 2 | 77 |

Can anyone help how this can be done?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like straight-forward `GROUP BY (label1 + label2 + label3)` to me.  What seems to be a problem?

Comment: Please, show your current code and describe what is the issue with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by the sum of labels, and for each of those groups sum the corresponding users:

```
SELECT (label1 + label2 + label3) as label_sum, sum(users) as user_sum
FROM your_table
GROUP BY (label1 + label2 + label3);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/83dbb/1)

Comment: Thank you! it worked!